# Embedding PyQtGraph in Qt without generating new Window

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I do not get how to embed PyQtGraph in my MainWindow without generating a new window like it is done by using

```
pg.plot(...)
```

What is the easiest way for doing that ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pyqtgraph provides a [long list of widgets](http://pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/index.html) which can be embedded. The [documentation for pg.plot()](http://pyqtgraph.org/documentation/functions.html#pyqtgraph.plot) states that this function creates and displays a [PlotWidget](http://pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/plotwidget.html#pyqtgraph.PlotWidget), so that's probably the one you want.

Example:

```
my_plot = pg.PlotWidget()
my_layout.addWidget(my_plot)
my_plot.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: @dan_0 you need to accept an answer as correct if that worked out for the question you asked!